# Transparency in PNGs with reportlab 2.3

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, reportlab

I have two PNGs that I am trying to combine into a PDF using ReportLab 2.3 on Python 2.5.  When I use canvas.drawImage(ImageReader) to write either PNG onto the canvas and save, the transparency comes out black.  If I use PIL (1.1.6) to generate a new Image, then paste() either PNG onto the PIL Image, it composits just fine.  I've double checked in Gimp and both images have working alpha channels and are being saved correctly.  I'm not receiving an error and there doesn't seem to be anything my google-fu can turn up.

Has anybody out there composited a transparent PNG onto a ReportLab canvas, with the transparency working properly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Passing the **mask parameter** with a value of 'auto' to `drawImage` fixes this for me.

```
drawImage(......., mask='auto')
```

[More information on the drawImage-function](http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/dev/pdfgen.html#reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas.drawImage)

Comment: FYI the `drawImage` docs are available here: http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/dev/pdfgen.html#reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas.drawImage

Comment: The online docs generated with Sphinx are very poor documentation. Instead I found more useful the userguide pdf http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf For this particular issue, see "Image methods" section in chapter 2 "Graphics and Text with pdfgen". They explain about the mask param keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that `mask='auto'` has stopped working for me with reportlab 3.1.8. In the docs it says to pass the values that you want masked out. So what works for me now is `mask=[0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, ]`. Basically it looks like this `mask=[red_start, red_end, green_start, green_end, blue_start, blue_end, ]

> The mask parameter lets you create transparent images. It takes 6
>   numbers and defines the range of RGB values which will be masked out
>   or treated as transparent. For example with [0,2,40,42,136,139], it
>   will mask out any pixels with a Red value from 0 or 1, Green from 40
>   or 41 and Blue of 136, 137 or 138 (on a scale of 0-255). It's
>   currently your job to know which color is the 'transparent' or
>   background one.

UPDATE: That masks out anything that is `rgb(0, 0, 0)` or `rgb(1, 1, 1)` which obviously might not be the right solution. My problem was people uploading png images with a gray color space. So I need to still figure out a way to detect the color space of the image. and only apply that mask on gray space images.

Comment: I'm using a black and white image. Can't seem to figure out a fix so I just photoshopped the image to have a white background. Way, way, way faster.

Comment: @varagrawal If you open your original image in photoshop you should check what color space it is using. It is probably gray scale. If you were to change the color space to RGB the image would look the same but it would be a little large of file size, but that would work and you could keep the transparency.

Answer (score 1):

ReportLab uses PIL for managing images. Currently, PIL trunk has patch applied to support transparent PNGs, but you will have to wait for a 1.1.6 release if you need stable package.